# How to Serialize/Deserialize DataSets keeping its metadata, sent from a client application in .NET Framework 4.7.2 to a gRPC service in Core 3.1

Tags: .net, wcf, dataset, grpc, protobuf-net

The requirement is to migrate a WCF service using Datasets to a gRPC service keeping the metadata when sending the data from the client to the service to identify Row modifications so we can update the database accordingly.

I'm working on a PoC serializing the DataSet as shown next:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
      dataSet.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;
      BinaryFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
      fmt.Binder = DataSetSerializationBinder.Default;
      fmt.Serialize(ms, dataSet);
      ms.Flush();
      return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Sending the byte array from the client to the service and then in the service deserializing using the following:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(datasetBytes)) {
      ms.Position = 0;
      BinaryFormatter fmt = new BinaryFormatter();
      fmt.Binder = DataSetSerializationBinder.Default;                    
      var des = fmt.Deserialize(ms);
      DataSet ds = (DataSet)des;
      ms.Close();
}
```

Overriding the SerializationBinder like this:

```
public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName){
    if (assemblyName.Equals("DSSerializer"))
        return typeof(System.Data.DataSet);
    else
        return defaultBinder.BindToType(assemblyName, typeName);
}
public override void BindToName(Type serializedType, out string assemblyName, out string typeName)
{
    assemblyName = "DSSerializer";
    typeName = serializedType.FullName;            
}
```

The Serialize and Deserialize methods are in the same library referenced from the client and the server,
but when trying to Deserialize it throws the exception: **Member 'XmlSchema' was not found**.
And before adding the SerializationBinder, the exception was: BinaryFormatter.Deserialize: **specified cast is not valid.**

Note that I need to transfer both schema information and [`DataRow.RowState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.rowstate) information.  When I tried to transfer my DataSet using XML as shown by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12461911/3744182) to *[Loading a datatable into a xml and xml back into a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12455539/3744182)*:

```
dataSet.WriteXml(ms, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(ms, XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
```

I found that the latter seems not to be transferred.  This is confirmed by *[Preserving DataRowState when serializing DataSet using DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2901191/3744182)*.

I understand BinaryFormatter is not the best option, what would be a better way to do it, or is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Honestly, sending DataSet (or even working with DataSet) sounds like the real problem here. There are very few problems where DataSet is a good solution. Is it even remotely possible to change them to use POCOs?

Comment: You can use XML instead of binary.  Just write the `DataSet` to XML using `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` and read it using `XmlReadMode.ReadSchema` and your schema will be preserved, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12461911/3744182) to [Loading a datatable into a xml and xml back into a datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12455539/3744182) by [SpaceApple](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1140144/spaceapple).

Comment: In fact I think this may be a duplicate, agree?

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you for your answer. This is a legacy service and it is being used by a windows forms application which is tightly coupled to datasets, unfortunately. So it would take a lot of work to change it to POCOs

Comment: Thank you @dbc, i tested it but, although it keeps the schema, what i need to send is the DataRow.RowState information to the service in order to identify any modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem here: [fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FuIkyN).  You need to serialize the [`RowState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.rowstate) information of a `DataSet` which seems only to be serialized by `BinaryFormatter`, but not by XML even when writing with `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema` and reading with `XmlReadMode.ReadSchema`.

Now, according to *[Cutting Edge: Binary Serialization of DataSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2004/october/cutting-edge-binary-serialization-of-datasets)* written by Dino Esposito in October 2004, what BinaryFormatter actually serializes is the [**schema**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.getschema) of the data set plus the [**diffgram**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/diffgrams) of the data set.  Since `DataSet` has methods to read and write both its schema and its diffgram, it should be possible to convert a data set to and from a DTO that contains these two properties without loss of `RowState` information.

The following DTO does the job:

```
public class DataSetDTO
{
    public string XmlSchema { get; set; }
    public string XmlDiffGram { get; set; }
    
    public static DataSetDTO FromDataSet(DataSet dataSet, bool indent = false)
    {
        var diffGram = new StringBuilder();
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(new StringWriter(diffGram), new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = indent }))
            dataSet.WriteXml(xmlWriter, XmlWriteMode.DiffGram);
        
        var schema = new StringBuilder();
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(new StringWriter(schema), new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = indent }))
            dataSet.WriteXmlSchema(xmlWriter);
        
        return new DataSetDTO
        {
            XmlSchema = schema.ToString(),
            XmlDiffGram = diffGram.ToString(),
        };
    }
    
    public DataSet ToDataSet()
    {
        var dataSet = new DataSet();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(XmlSchema))
        {
            // TODO: determine whether and how to deny resolving external references, as is done in the reference source
            // https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/DataSet.cs,388
            dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(new StringReader(XmlSchema));
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(XmlDiffGram))
        {
            using var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(XmlDiffGram));
            dataSet.ReadXml(reader, XmlReadMode.DiffGram);
        }
        return dataSet;
    }
}
```

If I round-trip a `DataSet` using the following method:

```
static DataSet RoundTripViaDTO(DataSet set) => DataSetDTO.FromDataSet(set).ToDataSet();
```

The schema, row data and `RowState` information are all deserialized successfully.  Demo here: [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JQ8581).

Notes:

- The DTO can be communicated between your client and server using any serializer you prefer.  However, **don't use `BinaryFormatter`**, for the reasons explained in *[What are the deficiencies of the built-in BinaryFormatter based .Net serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/703073/3744182)* as well as the [documentation remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=net-5.0#remarks) which state

  > BinaryFormatter is insecure and can't be made secure. For more information, see the [BinaryFormatter security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide).

  You are currently using .NET Core 3.1, but, looking forward, `BinaryFormatter` is marked as obsolete in .NET 5 and `BinaryFormatter` serialization is prohibited by default for ASP.NET apps.  See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete) for details.
- Since the diffgram data can be verbose I disabled formatting when writing it to a string.  If the resulting strings are very large, you might consider replacing the DTO with some sort of streaming solution.
- In the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/DataSet.cs,388) for `DataSet`, when the schema is loaded resolving of external references is disabled.

  ```
  this.ReadXmlSchema(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(strSchema)), true);

  internal void ReadXmlSchema(XmlReader reader, bool denyResolving) { //...
  ```

  However, the API to load a schema from an `XmlReader` and deny resolving is internal.  For security reasons you may want to investigate how to deny resolving using publicly available APIs.  See *[XmlSchemaSet Class: Security Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaset?view=net-5.0#security-considerations)* for issues that may arise from reading schemas from untrusted sources.
- This solution assumes the incoming data set is exactly of type `DataSet` and not some [typed DataSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/typed-datasets) subclass.  If you are working with typed data sets you will need to enhance the DTO to include the type information.

Comment: this really helped me solving the problem. Thank you very much! @dbc